# cp: cannot stat. No such file or directory, using cp in shell script

Tags: shell

I try to copy a bunch of files in to some directories and I build a shell scipt:

```
for j in {0..329}
do      
        mkdir ./sub$j/slice{0..18}
        for i in {0..18}
        do
                cp ./sub$j/slice_{$(($i*10))..$(($i*10+9))}.jpg ./sub$j/slice$i
        done
done
```

But it always said the `file ./sub0/slice_{0..9}.jpg doesnt exist`.

But `cp ./sub0/slice_{0..9}.jpg ./sub0/slice0` works fine.

Could someone tell me where is the bug? Thank you

Comment: You cannot use variables in brace expansions.  (Technically, this is because, as the shell processes a line, the brace expansions are done __before__ variable substitutions.)

Comment: @John1024 hi, thank you for your reply, in my case, do you have solutions?

Comment: If I understand what you are doing correctly, try `cp "./sub$j/slice_${i}"[0-9].jpg "./sub$j/slice$i"`

Comment: @John1024, hi, it doesn't work for me. Besides. I just do it manually(repeat several times) instead using the brace expansions..not efficient but it could be used. thank you for your help.

Comment: In general, when discussing computer issues, "it doesn't work" is not a useful response. If the problem is still not solved & you want help, give details. For example, did it generate an error message? If so, exactly what message. Did it not copy all the files you wanted? If so, exactly which files were not copied? Did it copy too many files? If so, which ones? etc.

Answer (score 0):

your command `mkdir` is not creating parent dirs.
you should use `-p` to create parent dirs if not exist

```
for j in {0..329}
do      
        mkdir -p ./sub$j/slice{0..18}
        for i in {0..18}
        do
                cp ./sub$j/slice_{$(($i*10))..$(($i*10+9))}.jpg ./sub$j/slice$i
        done
done
```